# Generalize methods with common signature

Tags: scala

I have bunch of methods as follow

```
def functionOne(param1: String, param2: Int): ReturnTypeOne = {
  doSomethingWith(param1, param2, new ReturnTypeOne)
}

def functionTwo(param1: String, param2: Int): ReturnTypeTwo = {
  doSomethingWith(param1, param2, new ReturnTypeTwo)
}
.....
def functionN(param1: String, param2: Int): ReturnTypeN = {
  doSomethingWith(param1, param2, new ReturnTypeN) 
}
```

Is there way to generalize these method in Scala? Any suggestion?

Comment: why don't you pass one, two, ...n as a parameter to your function?

Comment: Generalize based on what they do? In that case, we would want to see the definitions for these methods.

Comment: So the 3rd argument to `doSomethingWith()` is also the return type of the method?  Why use `functionX()` at all when `doSomethingWith()` does everything you need?

Comment: @jwvh This is inside wrapper so I have to use this class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure what "generalize" means. Something like this maybe?

```
trait F[A] {
  def f(x: String, y: Int): A
}

object F {
  def f[A](x: String, y: Int)(implicit ev: F[A]) = ev.f(x, y)

  implicit object FInt extends F[Int] {
    def f(x: String, y: Int) = y
  }

  implicit object FString extends F[String] {
    def f(x: String, y: Int) = x
  }
}

import F._

f[Int]("123", 1) //> 1
f[String]("123", 1) //> "123"
```

Comment: I want to pass return type as a param too so that I have only one function `val firstVal = myFunction("q", 1, ReturnTypeOne)`
`val secondVal = myFunction("a", 2, ReturnTypeTwo)`

Comment: Then Victor's answer does what you want.

Comment: @αƞjiβ You can't really pass type as a method parameter, type is not an object. But you can use type polymorphism as in my example.

Comment: @VictorMoroz May be I didn't explain clearly. I have updated the question to show my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe group them:

```
def functions (param1: String, param2: Int) = new {
  def one: ReturnTypeOne = ???
  def two: ReturnTypeTwo = ???
  def n: ReturnTypeN = ???
}

...
functions("a", 4).one

functions("b", 7).two
```

Comment: You want to instantiate a new object every time you want to call `one`? Sounds wasteful for me.

Comment: @VictorMoroz maybe... can't say without knowing the purpose... premature optimization and such...